# Where are scala js dependencies (specified with %%%) downloaded from, and how can I search for them?

Tags: scala.js

I want to see whether a particular library has been compiled for scala JS.

I know I could go to webjars and add it, but how can I find out whether I can just use the triple percent (`%%%`) syntax to declare it as a dependency like:

`libraryDependencies += "com.github.crocodilejs" %%% "frisbee" % "1.1.3"`

For normal jars I can search `mvnrepository.com` and similar - what is there for searching scala JS dependencies so I don't have to create my own with webjars?

Also, is there anything like http://definitelytyped.org/ for scalajs so I can find preexisting facades for JS libraries?

Comment: You might also want to consider the Scaladex: https://index.scala-lang.org/

Comment: @gzm0 Thanks that's easier to search than mvnrepository. I couldn't find a jquery facade on there but there is one on scaladex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @gzm0's answer:

You can indeed search for Scala.js libraries at http://search.maven.org/ with the `_sjs` suffix, but an easier way might be to use the [Scaladex](https://index.scala-lang.org/), which is an index of all Scala libraries. There is [a filter for Scala.js libraries](https://index.scala-lang.org/search?q=targets:scala.js_0.6).

The most important Scala.js libraries are also listed on the website at https://www.scala-js.org/libraries/

As for an equivalent of DefinitelyTyped, it is actually Maven Central *as well*, because Scala.js type facades are nothing more than Scala.js libraries. You can find a list of known existing facade libraries at https://www.scala-js.org/libraries/facades.html, which basically *is* the DefinitelyTyped of Scala.js.

Comment: That's really handy and just what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Scala.js jars are published on maven central as well. All you have to do is look for the _sjs suffix in the name.

I'm taking `com.chuusai`, `shapeless` as an example.

For Scala 2.11, you'll find the artifact `shapeless_2.11`. For Scala 2.11 and Scala.js 0.6.x, you'll find the artifact `shapeless_sjs0.6_2.11`.